# MySQL syntax error with PDO query

Tags: php, pdo

i am trying to use mysql function FROM_UNIXTIME together with PDO:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."_logins SET num_of_trys = num_trys-1, 
       last_try = FROM_UNIXTIME(:last_try), WHERE username = :username 
       OR ip = :ip");
$sth->bindParam(':ip', $ip); 
$sth->bindParam(':username', $user);
$sth->bindParam(':last_try', $lst);
$sth->execute();
```

But i get error message. What is right way to do this?

Here is error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: 
             Syntax   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
             in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
             MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
             'WHERE username = 'sadas' OR ip = '1834871734'' at line 1' 
              in /pathtofile/acc_functions.php:72 Stack trace: #0 
              /pathtofile/acc_functions.php(72): PDOStatement->execute() #1 
              /pathtofile/login.php(44): check_login_attempts(1834871734, 
              1343941422, 'sadas') #2 {main} thrown in 
              /pathtofile/acc_functions.php on line 72
```

Comment: Might it have something to do with the comma before your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I have add error message, calm down people, i just hit publish button too early :)

Comment: @Palladium damn, i am blind :/ Problem solved... I tought that is some other type of problem, becouse i am new in PDO...

Comment: @SomeoneS: Usually when a syntax error occurs, look directly before where MySQL told you the error occurred. That's usually the place it's in.

Comment: This is *nothing* to do with PDO. Please use/play with MySQL in the CLI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `,` character you have before `WHERE`.